# How do I refresh tempo js to display new data?

Tags: javascript, tempo

Been using Tempo.js for a while now and it's brilliant.

I can't seem to work out how to clear the existing content and then display new content.

I've used a function to send in the new parameter but it's not updating, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

```
    function getPic(imageChoice){


    $(document).ready(function() {
                                            var ecwidapi = Tempo.prepare('pictureView_ecwidme');
                                            ecwidapi.starting();
                                            $.getJSON("http://app.ecwid.com/api/v1/1010101010/product?id=" + imageChoice + "&callback=?", function(data) {                                              
                                                ecwidapi.render(data);
                                            });
                                        }); 
  }//close function getPic
```

Answer (score 1):

If it still relevant, you should save prepared object (ecwidapi) somewhere, and use it. you have ecwidapi.clear() or you can call ecwidapi.render again with new object state